# How to properly type PHP URL Syntax

Tags: php

Just a basic query but, at the moment I have a URL redirecting to another page like so:

```
"<a href='add-job.php?driver_id=" . $drive->driver_id . "". $drive->user_ID ."'>";
```

At the moment it only takes driver_ id  to the next page. is it possible to bind another element to the url from the database such as user id?

If so, how?

Comment: "<a href='add-job.php?driver_id=" . $drive->driver_id . "&user_id=". $drive->user_ID ."'>";

Comment: Personally I prefer using `sprintf` or `printf` (based on what you want to do) instead as it increases readability: `printf('<a href="add-job.php?driver_id=%d&user_id=%d">Link text</a>', $drive->driver_id, $drive->user_ID);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add variable name you want to send with prefix &**

```
echo " <a href='add-job.php?driver_id=" . $drive->driver_id . "&user_id". $drive->user_ID ."'>";
```

Comment: that works thanks, however upon reaching the next page, I put it into a variable like so: $login = $_GET['user_ID'];. but for some reason its saying user_id is undefined. any ideas?

Comment: check the variable name , according to this URL the variable must be $login = $_GET['user_id'];